# update a column with consecutive numbers starting with 1 for the same ID of products in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 column. want to update order column for each PId in sql. need a update statement to result below. any help appreciated.

```
ID    PId    Order

  1    2    0    
  2    2    0    
  3    2    0    
  4    3    0    
  5    3    0    
  6    4    0    
  7    4    0    
  8    5    0    
  9    5    0    
  10   6    0    
  11   6    0    
  12   6    0
```

the result will be as

```
ID   PId    Order

  1    2    1    
  2    2    2    
  3    2    3    
  4    3    1    
  5    3    2    
  6    4    1    
  7    4    2    
  8    5    1    
  9    5    2    
  10   6    1    
  11   6    2    
  12   6    3
```

which order is numbered concerning the PID Column.

Comment: What RDBMS (SQL flavor) you use?

Comment: one problem is that you have 3 records with the exact same data...is there another column to differentiate them?

Comment: Yes I have the Id Column to differentiate and edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later you can use the following:

```
Select 
    PId,
    Row_Number() Over (Partition By PId Order By PId) As [Order]
From 
    orders
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update:

```
UPDATE t
SET order = new_order
FROM t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT id, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY id) AS new_order
 FROM t) sub ON t.id = sub.id
```

Tested here: http://rextester.com/IJGT34576.

Comment: Sweet - glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

Because the other answers seems to presume SQL Server, the best way in that database is:

```
with topdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by pid order by id) as new_order
      from t
     )
update toupdate
     set [Order] = new_order;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.

What if I had a pre order starting with different numbers for example -1 0 1 2 3 or -2 -1 0 1 2 3 and wanted to save the order but with new order staring with 1 for all columns? in other word if I want to set orders according to the orders existing befor how will be the code?

Comment: @emin . . . Questions should be asked as *questions*, not comments, along with appropriate sample data, desired results, explanations, and the appropriate database tag.  This answer does not depend on the value in `order`, so any values originally in that column don't affect the results.